# Android: Does the app still work if the DOMAIN from which a dependency imported is cancelled or removed?

Tags: android

Suppose, For example, I have added a dependency like com.mydependency.blabla in my android app. And later if the domain mydependency.com is removed from the web. Will the features in my app still work?

Comment: Yes, it works if you already imported that into your app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will still work, two reasons:

- The package name is conventionally chosen to begin with a domain but actually has nothing to do with the domain on the internet.
- All dependencies are imported to your app at build time. It does not matter if they disappear afterwards.